# php pdo multiple row insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having some trouble inserting multiple rows in one pdo query.
I use this code that I've made.
But when I look inserts in the db the autoincrement id rising but some inserts are missing. Just the first insert stays in the db.

```
id  idcom   couleurb    couleurf    taille
169 160 blanc       grisfonc    Tableau L
170 161 blanc       grisfonce   Tableau L
172 162 blanc       grisfonce   Tableau L   

<?php    
foreach ($panier->getContenu() as $produit) {
    $queryTableau = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO tableaux (idcommande, colorfront, colorback, size, police, mots) VALUES (:id, :cf, :cb, :si, :po, :mo)');
    $queryTableau->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $queryTableau->bindParam(':cf', $cf);
    $queryTableau->bindParam(':cb', $cb);
    $queryTableau->bindParam(':si', $si);
    $queryTableau->bindParam(':po', $po);
    $queryTableau->bindParam(':mo', $mo);

    $description = $produit->getDescription();
    $id = $_SESSION['commande']['id'];
    $cf = $description['couleurFront'];
    $cb = $description['couleurBack'];
    $si = $produit->getNameProduit();
    $po = $description['police'];
    $mo = $description['mots'];

    $queryTableau->execute();
}
?>
```

Comment: did you check the values? var_dump($description) at the very least?

Comment: $description is good i just check

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the prepare on each foreach iteration.

```
<?php    

$queryTableau = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO tableaux (idcommande, colorfront, colorback, size, police, mots) VALUES (:id, :cf, :cb, :si, :po, :mo)');

foreach ($panier->getContenu() as $produit) {

    $queryTableau->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $queryTableau->bindParam(':cf', $cf);
    $queryTableau->bindParam(':cb', $cb);
    $queryTableau->bindParam(':si', $si);
    $queryTableau->bindParam(':po', $po);
    $queryTableau->bindParam(':mo', $mo);

    $description = $produit->getDescription();
    $id = $_SESSION['commande']['id'];
    $cf = $description['couleurFront'];
    $cb = $description['couleurBack'];
    $si = $produit->getNameProduit();
    $po = $description['police'];
    $mo = $description['mots'];
   $queryTableau->execute();
 }
?>
```

See if separating your data from the prepare/execute clears up some of your issues.

Comment: although this is right advice in general, it doesn't answer the question

Comment: I try both in and out the foreach for both binding and query

Answer (score 0):

According http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php Some drivers require to close cursor before executing next statement.

```
$queryTableau->execute();
$queryTableau->closeCursor();
```